# MySQL count (and sum) fields in multiple columns where 'not empty'

Tags: mysql, count

I'm using this MySQL query

```
SELECT COUNT(pros_a) + COUNT(pros_b) + COUNT(pros_c) + COUNT(pros_d) + COUNT(pros_e) AS pros_total FROM my_table WHERE contentid = 'id'
```

to count and sum fields in each column. But this returns ALL fields (full and empty). I want to count only filled fields, excluding empty fields. How can I do that? Just a little bit... confused! :)

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks

EDIT:

my_table

```
pros_a   pros_b   pros_c   pros_d   pros_e
-------  ------   ------   ------   ------
good     (empty)  good     good     (empty)
```

expected result

```
pros_total
----------
3
```

Comment: What is an `empty field` for you?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Salman A Yeah, sorry. Just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COUNT(column)` function does not count fields that are `NULL`. It counts empty (zero-length) strings though.

You can change these into:

```
COUNT( CASE WHEN column <> '' THEN column END )
```

or:

```
SUM(column <> '')
```

The last works in MySQL because `TRUE` is evaluated as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pros_a) + COUNT(DISTINCT pros_b) + COUNT(DISTINCT pros_c) + COUNT(DISTINCT pros_d) + COUNT(DISTINCT pros_e) FROM my_table WHERE contentid = 'id'
```

The above one should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use where condition for empty fields, for example WHERE pros_a != '' or pros_a != '0' if is NULL. pros_a != '' AND pros_b != ''